# How to include the ruport/acts_as_reportable gems for JRuby using Warbler?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, jrubyonrails, warbler, ruport

I am using JRuby 1.4.0 and want to use Ruport to make CSV files. This perfectly works until I make a war-file from it with warbler to put it on a server.

When I add the following code to environment.rb, JRuby complains there is `No such file to load -- 'ruport'`

```
 config.after_initialize do 
    require 'ruport' 
    require 'ruport/acts_as_reportable' 
  end
```

It works perfect locally, since I installed ruport and acts_as_reportable through `gem install ...`, but now I want to do it on a tomcat server and I've heard you can just add them to your gems folder to use it (does this need installation/configuration?).

I also added the needed gems with dependencies to the warble adding the following lines to warble.rb:

```
config.gems = ["ruport", "acts_as_reportable", "activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter", "rails", "rack"]
```

It still gives the same problem. All I found googling is the you should add `config.gem 'acts_as_reportable', :lib => 'ruport/acts_as_reportable'` to warble.rb, since the AAR gem is required that way. The problem is my JRuby version is only 1.4.0 and complains config.gem is a private method call and this only seems to work with more recent versions of JRuby.

Thanks!

Comment: Any reason you cannot upgrade JRuby?

Comment: When I start my app with version 1.6.2, I get an error message telling me to install the `activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter` gem. I did install the gem, but it still gives the same message and also complains about `ojdbc14.jar`. I already solved this in the old version but it comes back using 1.6.2...

Answer (score 0):

Warbler is based on [jruby-rack](https://github.com/nicksieger/jruby-rack/) .  You might want to review the gem.path setting
inside the web.xml file. I copy pasted the description from jruby-rack `JRuby-Rack Configuration` section below.

```
gem.path: Relative path to the bundled gem repository. Defaults to /WEB-INF/gems.
```

You get your app run inside Tomcat with just jruby-rack by following the jruby-rack documentation, if you are comfortable with Tomcat and the concept of webapps.